# not able to get file size in string with bytes to string converter in c#/XAML metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, properties, microsoft-metro, ivalueconverter

I just want to convert file size in string format like "1 MB" or "2.5 GB", I referred converter from [Q.42 library](http://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT) I think, I may be having mistake in my XAML code, please help me to figure out this.

MainPage.XAML

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ByteToStringConverter x:Key="BytesToString" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Size, Converter={StaticResource BytesToString}}"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.XAML.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFile f = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync("video.mp4");
        BasicProperties bs = await f.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.Size = bs.Size;
    }
}

public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ulong _Size;

    public ulong Size
    {
        get { return _Size; }
        set { _Size = value; OnPropertyChanged("Size");}
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

ByteToStringConverter.cs

```
public class ByteToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string size = "0 KB";

        if (value != null)
        {

            double byteCount = 0;

            byteCount = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);

            if (byteCount >= 1073741824)
                size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", byteCount / 1073741824) + " GB";
            else if (byteCount >= 1048576)
                size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", byteCount / 1048576) + " MB";
            else if (byteCount >= 1024)
                size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", byteCount / 1024) + " KB";
            else if (byteCount > 0 && byteCount < 1024)
                size = "1 KB";    //Bytes are unimportant ;)            
        }

        return size;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit: Updated to reflect new code]

First, tmplement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface in `MyClass` and fire the [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event when `Size` is changed. That will ensure the binding is updated.

Second, set the data binding of the page to an instance of `MyClass`, such as

```
<Page.DataContext> 
    <local:MyClass/> 
</Page.DataContext>
```

which you have indicated that you have done.

Third, instead of creating a new instance of `MyClass` in `OnNavigatedTo`, set the property on the instance the `MainPage` has bound to. For example:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile f = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync("video.mp4");
    BasicProperties bs = await f.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();

    // Do not create a new instance       
    ((MyClass) DataContext).Size = bs.Size;
}
```

**Why?** Binding in WPF is done to specific object instances. For example, if control A binds to object X and a property of object X changes, control A will be updated. If a control A binds to an object X but the value of another object Y changes, control A will not be notified.

Creating a new object in `OnNavigatedTo` created an object Y. Instead, you wanted to set the `Size` property on object X instead.

To debug this:

- Try it without the converter first to ensure the value is updated then add the converter. This will separate any converter issues from binding issues.
- Put a breakpoint in the setter for `Size`. If it is hit, the issue is with the binding. If not, the issue is that `Size` is not being set.

Very minor side point: Use a `ulong` instead of `double` in `Convert`. `ulong`s give 64 bits of precision whereas `doubles` only give 53 bits of precision. You may never see something that big in bytes but it also keeps it consistent with the property type in `MainPage`.

Comment: Still data is not getting bind with textblock, i tried with removing converter

Comment: What is the `DataContext` set to? Try setting it to the page itself.

Comment: Whose `DataContext` ? I tried in MainPage.xaml.cs with `this.DataContext = this`, but not working.

Comment: I read the updated code. Two changes. First: Set the binding to an instance of `MyClass`. not the page (possibly my mistake). Second: Store the MyClass object in a class field. Otherwise, it may go out of scope and be garbage collected.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the setter in the Size property and see if it is called. That will tell you whether the issue is before or after that.

Comment: I am not getting you. I think binding should be set with property name i.e. `Size` not the instance of class (here `MyClass`). If I am wrong then please post the whole code. I put this in MainPage.xaml
`<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MyClass/>
</Page.DataContext>`
I put breakpoint on setter, value is set but not being displayed.

Comment: It worked :) Can you please explain why creating new instance doesn't show the value ?

Comment: Added an explanation to the answer.